# How can i Call Apex Controller Class in Custom Button through JavaScript

Tags: apex, javascript

Button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}

sforce.apex.execute("LeadConversion","show",{});
```

Apex Class

```
global class LeadConversion 
{
    global static void show()
    {
         //Some Code Here
    }
}
```

I am trying like this and getting error `faultcode:soapenv:client',faultstring':no operation is availbale for request`, Please guide me here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mark method with webservice attribute like below

```
global class LeadConversion 
{
    webservice global static void show()
    {
         //Some Code Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! , it Worked. Thanks